# Backbone and Ajax request with undefined

Tags: ajax, json, backbone.js

I need to get some value (here rhOptions) so I make ajax call, but the problem is the view render this value as "undefined"
there is an extract of my View code:

```
UserView.prototype.initialize = function() {
      var self;
      console.log("Test000");
      self = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://test.redhand.com.pl/lampy/api/filter",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          self.rhOptions = data.rhOptions.tel;
        }
      });
      console.log(this.rhOptions);
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change invalid', this.render);
      this.render();
      return this.serverValidation = {};
    };

    UserView.prototype.render = function() {
      var firstInput, user;
      user = this.model.toJSON();
      user.error = this.model.validationError || {};
      _.extend(user.error, this.serverValidation);
      this.template(this.model.config('tpl'), {
        user: user,
        rhOptions: this.rhOptions
      });
      this.$('form').attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');
      firstInput = this.$('input[required][value=""]:first');
      _.defer(function() {
        if (!firstInput.val()) {
          return firstInput.select();
        }
      });
      return this;
    };
```

I try to rhOptions value in a View but it seems that View is render before I get the JSOn file, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I haven't tested it. Moved the render function into the success callback of the ajax call so that it gets the loaded data.

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    self.rhOptions = data.rhOptions.tel;
    console.log(self.rhOptions);
    self.listenTo(self.model, 'change invalid', self.render);
    self.render();
}
```